# Dropdown Select Arrow doesn't align properly

Tags: css

I have a select dropdown button but I'm having a problem with the arrow, is aligned at the end of the dropdown, which I want to have some padding it, I want to achieve that with CSS or js or in any form that is possible.

Here is the CSS:

```css
.select_box {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 1.025em;
    padding: 0.6em 1em;
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    transition: var(--animate);
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    outline: none;
    background: var(--header-bg);

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: var(--icon) 1px solid;
    }
}
```

And here is my Html:

```html
<select value='all'className={styles.select_box}>
          <option value='all'>{t('order.status_all')}</option>
          <option value='draft'>{t('order.status_draft')}</option>
          <option value='new'>{t('order.status_new')}</option>
          <option value='order_completed'>{t('order.status_created')}</option>
          <option value='invoiced'>{t('order.status_invoiced')}</option>
          <option value='paid'>{t('order.status_paid')}</option>
</select>
```

And here is how it looks:

[image: scr]

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Comment: @tushar no, i dont want to replace it

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the default arrow and then add an image inplace of that .
There is no styling that can style the default arrow icon .

The following code will **hide** the **default** arrow and include an image in place of that.

```
select {
    -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
    appearance:none;

/* Now add a background image */
    padding-right:10px;
    background-image:url("./image.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:calc(100%-3px);
    background-size:10px;
}
```

Hope this solves your doubt.

Comment: But i Want that specific icon

Comment: which icon do you want ?

Comment: You can add a div element , give position absolute to it and then you can customize it more.

Comment: FYI `calc(N-N)` is invalid syntax. Use spaces between the operator `calc(N - N)`